# How is an Index Seek satisfying this query?

Tags: sql-server, index, optimization, execution-plan

I'm using the AdventureWorks database and running the following query:

```
SELECT ct.Name
FROM Person.ContactType ct
WHERE ct.Name LIKE 'Own%'
```

The execution plan shows that it's using an `Index Seek (NonClustered)`, however, there is only one index on the table; that being the primary key on `ContactTypeID`.

[image]

The table is defined as follows:

```
/****** Object:  Table [Person].[ContactType]    Script Date: 15/10/2016 20:43:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [Person].[ContactType](
    [ContactTypeID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [dbo].[Name] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ContactType_ContactTypeID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContactTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [Person].[ContactType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ContactType_ModifiedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModifiedDate]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Primary key for ContactType records.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ContactTypeID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Contact type description.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Name'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Date and time the record was last updated.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ModifiedDate'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Default constraint value of GETDATE()' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType', @level2type=N'CONSTRAINT',@level2name=N'DF_ContactType_ModifiedDate'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Primary key (clustered) constraint' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType', @level2type=N'CONSTRAINT',@level2name=N'PK_ContactType_ContactTypeID'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Lookup table containing the types of business entity contacts.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'Person', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'ContactType'
GO
```

Comment: The `AK` comes from Alternate Key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AK_ContactType_Name index is a unique nonclustered index on the Name field:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AK_ContactType_Name] ON [Person].[ContactType]
(
    [Name] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

There are two indexes on this table by default - the primary clustered key, plus the above one.

Comment: Yes, found it.  Was being stupid.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problemo, live to serve.